# How to zip (archive/compress in .zip) a file inside SOA using BPEL?

Tags: soap, ftp, soa, oracle12c, bpel

I have a requirement to pick a .dat file from a remote server and move to a content server using soap but as a zip file. What is the best way to achieve the same? I am using SOA 12c. Is java embedding a way to do so? What are the other ways?

Comment: Are you using a FTP adapter or a File Adapter to get the .dat file ? Do you need to do any transformation on the content of the file before submiting the zipped file in a SOAP ?

Comment: No transformation needed. Simply need to zip it. I am using a file adapter.

Comment: I would advise creating a spring context that take the dat file as an input (the file adapter encode it in base64 by default), decode it, zip it, encode it and send it to a BPEL process that will build the payload and invoke the SOAP connection